# Pack two types into one CUDA

Tags: cuda

I'd like to pack two data types, specifically an `int` and a `float` into an `unsigned long long int` in CUDA.

I wrote something like this but I get compilation errors when unpacking:

```
__global__ void kernel() {
  // pack
  float positive_num = 5.1034786f; 
  int index = 1024;
  unsigned long long int u_int_val = (unsigned long long int) positive_num << 32;
  u_int_val += index & 0xffff;
  // unpack 
  positive_num = (float)  u_int_val >> 32 ;
  index = u_int_val & 0xffff ;
  // check
  printf("positive_num: %f - index %i\n", positive_num, index);
}
```

The error I get:

```
error: expression must have integral or unscoped enum type // error line - positive_num = (float) ...
```

I have tried in multiple ways, even casting the memory address, either I get compilation errors or simply I don't manage to have a precise conversion straight and back.

If helps, the only assumption I can make is that both the numbers are positive, hence `float positive_num > 0.f; int index > 0;`

The reason I need to pack two numbers into one, is to embed everything (a `float` and and `int`) in a single atomic operation, to find the minimum of both for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
__device__ unsigned long long pack(int a, float b){

  return (((unsigned long long)(*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(&a))))<<32) + *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(&b));
}

__device__ void unpack(unsigned long long val, int &a, float &b){
  unsigned mb = (unsigned)val;
  b = *(reinterpret_cast<float *>(&mb));
  unsigned ma = (unsigned)(val >> 32);
  a = *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&ma));
}
```

(This is not really unique to CUDA.  This is just C++ code, apart from the `__device__` decorators.)

Example:

```
$ cat t2169.cu
#include <cstdio>

    __device__ unsigned long long pack(int a, float b){

      return (((unsigned long long)(*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(&a))))<<32) + *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(&b));
    }

    __device__ void unpack(unsigned long long val, int &a, float &b){
      unsigned mb = (unsigned)val;
      b = *(reinterpret_cast<float *>(&mb));
      unsigned ma = (unsigned)(val >> 32);
      a = *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&ma));
    }


__global__ void k(int a, float b){

  unsigned long long val = pack(a,b);
  int ma;
  float mb;
  unpack(val, ma, mb);
  printf("a = %d, b = %f\n", ma, mb);
}

int main(){

  k<<<1,1>>>(-2, -1.3f);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t2169 t2169.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2169
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
a = -2, b = -1.300000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

That packs the `int` quantity in the upper 32-bits and the `float` quantity in the lower 32-bits.

If you want to reverse the storage order, you can just reverse the usage of `a` and `b` like this:

```
__device__ unsigned long long pack(int a, float b){

  return (((unsigned long long)(*(reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(&b))))<<32) + *(reinterpret_cast<unsigned *>(&a));
}

__device__ void unpack(unsigned long long val, int &a, float &b){
  unsigned ma = (unsigned)val;
  a = *(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&ma));
  unsigned mb = (unsigned)(val >> 32);
  b = *(reinterpret_cast<float *>(&mb));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the need for heterogeneous packing and unpacking exists only in device code, one can use CUDA's device function intrinsics `__float_as_int()` and `__int_as_float()` to re-interpret a 32-bit `float` into a 32-bit `int` and vice versa. The packing of integers is unproblematic, simply shift the desired high-order part and OR the parts together.

For the same functionality in code that needs to work on both host and device, the canonical C++ way of re-interpreting floating-point data as integer data and vice versa is to use `memcpy()`; CUDA is a C++ derivative. This may or may not be as efficient as using the device intrinsics, which have no cost, as the 32-bit registers of the GPU can be used for both integer and floating-point data. It may be worthwhile to inspect the generated machine code (SASS) with `cuobjdump --dump-sass`.

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define DEVICE_CODE_ONLY  (0)

#if DEVICE_CODE_ONLY
__device__ unsigned long long int pack_float_int (float a, int b)
{
    return (((unsigned long long int)(unsigned int)__float_as_int (a)) << 32) |
        (unsigned long long int)(unsigned int)b;
}

__device__ void unpack_float_int (unsigned long long int a, float *f, int *i)
{
    *f = __int_as_float ((int)(unsigned int)(a >> 32));
    *i = (int)(unsigned int)a;
}

#else // DEVICE_CODE_ONLY

__host__ __device__ unsigned long long int pack_float_int (float a, int b)
{
    unsigned int t;
    memcpy (&t, &a, sizeof t);
    return ((unsigned long long int)t << 32) |
        (unsigned long long int)(unsigned int)b;
}

__host__ __device__ void unpack_float_int (unsigned long long int a, float *f, int *i)
{
    unsigned int t = (unsigned int)(a >> 32);
    memcpy (f, &t, sizeof (*f));
    *i = (int)(unsigned int)a;
}
#endif // DEVICE_CODE_ONLY

__global__ void kernel (float f, int i)
{
    unsigned long long int p;
    float uf;
    int ui;

    p = pack_float_int (f, i);
    printf ("GPU: packed (%15.8e, %d) into %016llx\n", f, i, p);
    unpack_float_int (p, &uf, &ui);
    printf ("GPU: unpacked %016llx into (%15.8e %d)\n", p, uf, ui);
}

int main (void)
{ 
    float f = 5.1034786f;
    int i = 1024;
    printf ("testing packing/unpacking: %s\n", 
            DEVICE_CODE_ONLY ? "on device" : "on device and host");
    kernel<<<1,1>>> (f, i);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
#if !DEVICE_CODE_ONLY
    unsigned long long int p;
    float uf;
    int ui;
    p = pack_float_int (f, i);
    printf ("CPU: packed (%15.8e, %d) into %016llx\n", f, i, p);
    unpack_float_int (p, &uf, &ui);
    printf ("CPU: unpacked %016llx into (%15.8e %d)\n", p, uf, ui);
#endif // DEVICE_CODE_ONLY
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```